# Image source not readable , whats wrong

Tags: php, laravel

am new to Laravel 8, I created a controller called PostsController and I have a file called create.blade.php which has a form with input entry and an image, after filling an entry and choosing an image , the image is supposed to be displayed in index.blade.php
but I get an error that Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException
Image source not readable but the image get saved in the folder

here is my PostsController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
public function create(){
    return view('posts.create');
 }
 public function store(){
    $data = request()->validate([
        'caption' => 'required',
        // 'another' => '',
        // 'image' => 'required|image',
        'image' => ['required','image']
    ]);
    $imagePath = (request('image')->store('uploads','public'));
    $image = 
   Image::make(public_path("storage/app/public/uploads/{$imagePath}"))->fit(100,100);
    $image->save();
    auth()->user()->posts()->create([
        'caption' => $data['caption'],
        'image' => $imagePath,
    ]);
    \App\Models\Post::create($data);
   dd(request()->all());

return redirect('/profile/'. auth()->user()->id);
}
public function show(\App\Models\Post $post){
    return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
}
}
```

here is my index.blade.php

Answer (score 2):

`Image::make(public_path("storage/app/public/uploads/{$imagePath}"))->fit(100,100);`

This line uses `public_path` which refers to your `public` folder, so you're looking for the image inside `public/storage/app/public/uploads/...` instead of `storage/app/public/uploads/...`.
You should be using `storage_path` (see https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-storage-path)

Considering what I said, you'd be doing something like

`Image::make(storage_path("app/public/uploads/{$imagePath}"))->fit(100,100);`

Comment: $imagePath = (request('image')->store('uploads','public'));

Comment: do i have to change 'public' in  $imagePath = (request('image')->store('uploads','public')); to 'storage'

Comment: no you're hitting storage/public/uploads not storage/uploads/public

Comment: I have used  $image = Image::make(storage_path("app/public/uploads/{$imagePath}"))->fit(100,100); but the error still comes,

Comment: but the image goes to uploads, whats giving me headache is it can't be displayed